# SELECT query within FOR Each Loop

Tags: php, select, foreach

I have a form with multiple rows with the following POST fields for each row: I1, G1 ,Grade_System_id, F1

On Form submit, I want to lookup the Grades table for the Grade_Points for each of the POST values of $G1 and Grade_System_id.

I have echoed all the POST values and they submit fine,and run the query against the databasd and it runs fine. When I run this PHP script, the SQL script within the loop will not return Grade_Points? I have been working on this for over a week to get it to work with no luck. Any help appreciated.

```php
foreach ($_POST['F1'] as $Lesson_Class_id => $Response)  {
    $I1 = $_POST['I1'][$Lesson_Class_id];  
    $G1 = $_POST['G1'][$Lesson_Class_id];

    echo "Grade=";
    echo $G1;
    echo"<br>";
    
    $Grade_System_id = $_POST['Grade_System_id'][$Lesson_Class_id];
    
    echo "Grade System ID=";
    echo $Grade_System_id;
    echo"<br>";
    
    $stmt = $conn -> prepare('SELECT Grade_Points FROM Grades WHERE Grade=? AND Grade_System_id=?');
        
    $stmt -> bind_param('si', $G1, $Grade_System_id);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> store_result();
    $stmt -> bind_result($Grade_Points);
    $stmt -> fetch();
    
    echo "Grade Points=";
    echo $Grade_Points;
    echo"<br>";
    
    echo "Lesson_Class_id=";
    echo $Lesson_Class_id;
    echo"<br>";
                
    echo "Response=";
    echo $Response;
    echo"<br>";

    if ($Response=="Completed") {
        $T_Points=$Grade_Points;
    }
            
    if ($Response!="Completed") {
            $T_Points="";
    }
         
    $stmt = $conn -> prepare('UPDATE Lesson_CLass SET I1 = ?, F1=?, T_Points=? WHERE Lesson_Class_id= ?');
    
    //echo 'Student ID:  ' . $Lesson_Class_id . ' Outcome: ' . $Response . "<br>";
        
    $stmt -> bind_param('ssss', $I1,$Response, $T_Points, $Lesson_Class_id);
    $stmt -> execute();
        
}
```

Comment: I’d start with turning PHP and MySQL error reporting on, and then checking the return values of `execute`

Comment: Have you checked your system logs? Quite possibly there's something in there to give you a clue.